# My .htaccess file might be incorrect

Tags: .htaccess

I am creating a .htaccess file that will compress my website. I copied and pasted the gzip code but when I tested the website it did not compress.

I placed my .htaccess file in the public/html directory along with other web pages, and I made sure to change the file name from the original txt file.

Here is the code from the .htaccess file

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 400 /400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
ErrorDocument 504 /504.html

AddType application/octet-stream .avi .mpg .mov .pdf .xls .mp4 .doc

# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

<FilesMatch ".(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing first, make sure your apache has mod_gzip or mod_deflate loaded
run this and check it

```
print_r(apache_get_modules());
```

note: for apache 2+ you need mod_deflate, for earlier versions mod_gzip (you may need to alter your htaccess file in that case)